# When opening app while keeping device in landscape mode then, on Portrait activity dialog is showing landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

As per product requirement I have to keep the orientation of app to portrait for mobile and landscape for tablet.
Used following code to set orientation for each activity in `onCreate()` callback before invoking `super.onCreate()`

```
public static void updateOrientation(Activity activity) {
    boolean hasAPI18 = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2;
    if (isTablet()) {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(hasAPI18 ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    } else {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(hasAPI18 ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

**Working scenario For Mobile:**

1. Keep device in portrait orientation
2. Open application
3. Do event to show dialog

**Result:** On portrait activity, Dialog show properly in portrait mode.

**Error scenario For Mobile:**

1. Keep device in landscape orientation
2. Open application
3. Do event to show dialog

**Result:** On portrait activity Dialog shows in landscapemode due to which only 2/3 part of dialog is visible.

**Verified:**

1. Activity orientation and window orientation is set to portrait while showing dialog on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue I updated the `supportLibraryVersion` from `23.1.2 to 24.1.1`. I am not sure about the root cause. I checked release note of supportLibrary but didn't any bug fixed related to this one. But updating support library version helped me to fix it. Hope it would help someone

Answer (score 0):

Have to add values folder as like below

```
values               (is_tablet=false) Mobile
values-sw600dp       (is_tablet=true)  7  inch Tablets
values-sw720dp       (is_tablet=false) 10 inch Tablets
```

in that add `bool.xml` which contains

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>
     <bool name="is_tablet">true</bool>
     </resources>
```

Get this values in all of activities and dialog set potrait for mobile and landscape for tablets

```
   if(getApplicationContext().getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet)){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }else{
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

Comment: As per product requirement I need to set orientation for tablet to landscape irrespective of Tab 10 inch or 7 inch and for mobile to portrait.

Comment: Thanks for help I am using same approach in code to determine if device is mobile,tablet or tv. As per my understanding there is some bug in my code itself that is causing this issue. I will update you once I find the bug, but currently I am struggling to find it.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
setRequestedOrientation(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

and add below line in manifest.

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

its working !

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: I tired your approach but it didn't work. I think there is something in my codebase that is causing this issue. But I am not able to figure out what is happenning

Comment: i am checking on mobile as well as TV